# Retrieve database content without linebreak

Tags: c#, asp.net

(asp.net C# project)

I am trying to show contact info in my footer, I receive the info from the database, but in my administrator panel I have CKEditor which adds linebreaks. So, what my problem is that I'd like my text in my footer to have no linebreak, is there any way of doing this?

How it looks in my contact page:

```
Adresse
Zip, City

Phone
Fax
```

How I would like it to be in my footer:

```
Adresse, Zip city, phone, fax
```

I receive the texts using:

```
<p><asp:Literal ID="LitContent" runat="server" /></p>
LitContent.Text = textService.GetText("ContactInfo");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LitContent.Text = textService.GetText("ContactInfo").Replace("<br />", " ");
```

but you should check how the BR is formatted from the editor. It may be capitalized or without /

It is also possible that the HTML generated by the editor uses paragraphs instead of br. In this case it becomes more complex to remove them. Basically to answer your question correctly we need more information. What is the actual string that GetText returns.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a formatting Problem.

There's a string and you can replace the Linebreaks out of a string. The code shown below do this by replacing the Linebreak with a blank. Should be the easiest way of doing this

```
infoText = textServices.GetText("ContactInfo");
infoText = infoText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
LitContent.Text = infoText;
```

Comment: Cheers, I just tried Stilgar's solution and it did the job so I'll leave it there before I mess it up, but thank you for your reply Benni.